# Cordova install , bad interpreter

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I followed [this tutorial](https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-linux.html) to install cordova,
but when I try to execute `cordova --version` I get this message:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/cordova: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Uninstall the existing cordova globally by `sudo npm uninstall cordova -g`
2. Restart the system
3. Install the cordova again `sudo npm install cordova -g`

Comment: After this, I get error
bash: /usr/local/bin/cordova: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: Or better say, nothing changed :)